# How to change the format in which datetime is stored in postgresql with sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, datetime, timestamp, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize ORM with the Postgresql database for my node.js application.

In the database, I have a field 'start_time' with type Sequelize.DATE.

In postman, if I run the API for inserting a value **'2020-05-30 02:00:00'** in that field, it is stored as **'2020-05-29 20:30:00+00:00'** in the database. What can I do to store it as I am passing in the database?

My locality is India which is GMT+05:30.

Comment: A `DATE` column has no format (it's just an integer) and thus you can't change it.  Any format you see is applied by whatever program _displays_ the value.

Comment: It is stored in UTC, What's the problem?  You can always convert this value to a local date/time.